# C# Sending File to VM Directory using VMware SDK InitiateFileTransferToGuest Protocol Error --> ResponseStream Error 22 <The File Name is not valid>

Tags: c#, file, upload, webclient, vmware

I am trying to send a file to a VM on a ESXi Server from an outside Client.
I am using the VMware SDK VMWare.Vim.dll.
When i try to use the URL given by the FileTransfer Request it Fails.
Code:

```
public static string ServerIP
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerIP"].ToString(); }
}

private string ServiceUrl = "https://" + ServerIP + "/sdk";
private string UserName = "ESXIUser";
ServiceContent sc = new ServiceContent();
VimClient client = new VimClientImpl();

public VmOps()
{
}

public void Connect(string password)
{
    // connect to vSphere web service
    sc = client.Connect(ServiceUrl);
    // Login using username/password credentials
    client.Login(UserName, password);
}

public void copyDatastoreFile(/*string VMName, string Folder, string sourceFilePath*/)
{
    string hostpass = "ESXIUserPAssword";
    string VMName = "VMname";
    string Folder = "Test";
    string FileName = "test.zip";
    //File destination info
    string BasePath = "D:";
    String targetDir = BasePath + "/" + Folder;
    string srcPath = BasePath + "/" + Folder + "/" + FileName;

    //Connect to the ESXi
    Connect(hostpass);
    NameValueCollection nvcFilter = new NameValueCollection();
    nvcFilter.Add("Name", VMName);
    var vm = (VirtualMachine)client.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, nvcFilter, null);

    GuestOperationsManager gom = new GuestOperationsManager(client, sc.GuestOperationsManager);
    gom.UpdateViewData();
    if (gom.FileManager == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    GuestFileManager gfm = new GuestFileManager(client, gom.FileManager);

    var Auth = new NamePasswordAuthentication { Password = "VMPassword", Username = "VMUSER", InteractiveSession = false };

    bool exists = false;

    GuestListFileInfo fInfo = gfm.ListFilesInGuest(vm.MoRef, Auth, BasePath, null,null, Folder);
    exists = fInfo.Files != null;
    if (!exists)
    {
        // Create directory where the files will be copied to
        gfm.MakeDirectoryInGuest(vm.MoRef, Auth, targetDir, true);
    }

    // Copy Virtual Machine file To
    string URL = gfm.InitiateFileTransferToGuest(vm.MoRef,
        Auth,
        targetDir + "/" + FileName,
        new GuestFileAttributes(),
        new FileInfo(srcPath).Length,
        true);
    UploadFile(srcPath, URL.Replace("*", ServerIP));            
}        

private void UploadFile(string from, string to)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string cookie = ((VimApi_60.VimService)client.VimService).CookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(((VimApi_60.VimService)client.VimService).Url))[0].ToString();
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ESXiUSER", "ESXIUserPAssword");
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);

        try
        {
            wc.UploadFile(to, "PUT", from);
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            if (wex.Response != null)
            {
                string pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();                        
            }
        }
        wc.Dispose();
    }
   }
```

URL Looks like: 
"https://199.199.0.1:443/guestFile?id=22&token=23e2deef-7979-b1a8-75e5-413440d8c1377"
Cookie Looks like:
"vmware_soap_session="5e24eaa312s1245de2gg213456m23b4bd87c8e1ca"

WebException:
The remote Server returned an error:(500) Internal Server Error

ResponseStream:
\n 22\n The file Name is not valid

Anyone any experience on file Transfers with VMware SDK? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry i am looking at you code i am trying to understand what - DSSAuth, every time i call  InitiateFileTransferToGuest  the code myself i get 'The operation is not supported on the object'. I can create directories but this method is failing.

Comment: I think it was a copy paste mistake, i guess it should be Auth, the authentication object to the server. See https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/converter-sdk/conv50_apireference/vim.vm.guest.FileManager.html for more information about initateFileTrasterToGuest

Comment: That has fixed it and now generates the url. Thanks for the prompt response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btw. it was a simple mistake, all slashs have to be switched with a double backslash. The VMWare sdk can handle the slash, but the webclient put can't.

example:

```
string targetDir = BasePath + "\\" + Folder;

string srcPath = BasePath + *"\\" + Folder + "\\" + FileName;
```